# Sunspot/Solr: non-alphabetical characters

Tags: ruby, solr, lucene, sunspot, dismax

I'm using Solr with Sunspot/dismax. Is it possible to query for non-alphabetic characters? I.e.:

`~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = [ ] { } | \`

I'm aware that `+/-` must be escaped, as they are dismax inclusion/exclusion operators. But I'm getting no matches when I search for any of these characters:

```
Foo.search { fulltext '=' }.results.length   # => 0
Foo.search { fulltext '\=' }.results.length  # => 0
```

Yet:

```
Foo.search { fulltext 'a'}.results.length    # => 30
```

Here is the tokenizer config I'm using:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: What tokenizer do you use? Are you sure that it doesn't drop the punctuation characters?

Comment: Updated my question with the tokenizers in use for "text".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr's `StandardTokenizer` drops all 'special characters', since it's optimized to use with plain text. So for example '=' won't be found because it's being stripped from the text during indexing.

One of tokenizers that preserve all characters is [`WhitespaceTokenizer`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory), which splits input only on whitespace. You need to evaluate if it's a good solution to your problem, as it will produce tokens like this:

> 20-year-old fox jumps over the lazy dog. -> '20-year-old', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog.'

It may happen that you will need to provide your own tokenizer (not necessary by implementing one, you can define appropriate regular expression for split characters and use [`PatternTokenizer`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory)) or use filter like [`WordDelimiterFilter`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) or [`PatternReplaceFilter`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory).